# Python regex not capturing groups properly

Tags: python, regex, invoice2data

I have the following regex `(?:RE:\w+|Reference:)\s*((Mr|Mrs|Ms|Miss)?\s+([\w-]+)\s(\w+))`.

Input text examples:

1. RE:11567 Miss Jane Doe 12345678
2. Reference: Miss Jane Doe 12345678
3. RE:J123 Miss Jane Doe 12345678
4. RE:J123 Miss Jane Doe 12345678 Reference: Test Company

**Sample Code:**

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(?:RE:\w+|Reference:)\s*((Mr|Mrs|Ms|Miss)?\s+([\w-]+)\s(\w+))')
result = pattern.findall('RE:11693 Miss Jane Doe 12345678')
```

For all 4 I expect the output `('Miss Jane Doe', 'Miss', 'Jane', 'Doe')`. However in 4th text example I get `[('Miss Jane Doe', 'Miss', 'Jane', 'Doe'), (' Test Company', '', 'Test', 'Company')]`

How can I get the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `^` to the start of the regex to only match at the start. This makes it
`^(?:RE:\w+|Reference:)\s*((Mr|Mrs|Ms|Miss)?\s+([\w-]+)\s(\w+))`.

Comment: This gives an error on 4th example `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: I actually can't reproduce your issue to begin with. What version of Python are you on? It works for me on 3.10.9.

Comment: Im on python 3.8

Comment: And sorry I've updated my question, was supposed to be findall instead of search

Comment: Could you clarify what your goal here is? `.search()` works here because it only searches from the start of the string. If you want the first match inside a larger string, you could do `pattern.findall('RE:J123 Miss Jane Doe 12345678 Reference: Test Company')[0]`.

Comment: Im using the `invoice2data` library and I believe its using `findall`. I only provide the library with the regex string. There is no option for specifying whether to use `search` or `findall`. I suspected it uses findall because of the output from 4th example

Comment: So `findall` ignores non capturing groups?

Comment: `search()` finds the first instance, whereas `findall`returns all instances. But if we add the `^` to the findall regex, we'll only get the result that begins at the start of the string. So if `invoice2data` truly does use `findall` ([which I think it does](https://github.com/invoice-x/invoice2data/blob/1adb49cb74b17e1dd278886ee4c432ed2dcaf443/src/invoice2data/extract/parsers/regex.py#L33)), that should work.

Comment: That worked thanks. I might have to dig into `invoice2data` to see how it works because even though the regex is working when I'm testing on jupyter its not returning results for the 4th example when using the library.